# How can I represent this description in set builder notation?

Tags: formal-languages, automata

The language that accepts strings with the number of 0s being congruent with 1%3 and an even number of 1s over the alphabet {0, 1}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible way:
$$
\{ w \in \{0,1\}^* : \text{the number of 0s in $w$ is congruent to 1 modulo 3, and the number of 1s is even} \}
$$